# How's is it called the fIlters with specific keywords like in Youtube app. android studio kotlin

Tags: kotlin, filter, youtube, keyword

I have a question, Using Kotlin in Android Studio. I want to make an app where you can filter through a recyclerView such as in the YouTube app. 
 how is this called? are there any tutorials that you know can help me? I would strongly appreciate all your help

[image: keywords]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is called a `Chip`, check this [article](https://medium.com/material-design-in-action/chips-material-components-for-android-46001664a40f). 
Look for the Filter Chips section.